# Could the border-image-* attributes be used separately in CSS3?

Tags: css

there are several attributes of border-image,such like border-image-source, border-image-slice, border-image-width, border-image-repeat, border-image-outset, **I read in one book which says that you should not use the attributes separately** like:

```
.border-image-class {
    border-image-source: url("image.jpg");
    border-image-slice: 10 20 10 20;
    border-image-releat: repeat;
}
```

you I should write it like this:

```
.border-image-class {
    border-image: url("image.jpg") 10 20 10 20 repeat
}
```

but the w3schools give some examples of use the attributes separately:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp

which one is right?

Comment: Both solutions are right. It depends on the coder's style. Combining the values may save some space and may be pleasing to some people, whereas seperated attributes ensure readability. I prefer using seperated attributes in SASS (except margin, padding and border).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any property that exists as a shorthand can also be declared using separate longhands. This includes `border-image`.

Which one you use is entirely up to you; however keep in mind that when declaring shorthands, any values you omit will be set to their initial values. This means if you use a shorthand after or in a more specific rule than a set of longhands, those longhands will be overridden even if they are not specified in the shorthand. For example if you did this:

```
.border-image-class {
    border-image-source: url("image.jpg");
    border-image: 10 20 10 20 repeat;
}
```

The `border-image-source` declaration will be ignored because it gets replaced in the shorthand with `none`.